# No route matches [GET] "/flare.json"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, d3.js, rails-routing

I'm using an example from `D3.js` that uses the `d3.json` function to load `flare.json` in Rails.
I've got the `flare.json` file in the same folder as my view. When i load the page i get this error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/flare.json"):
```

How can i tell rails to route this request to the flare.json file?

This is the code that preforms the load:

```
d3.json("flare.json", function(error, root) {
  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(bubble.nodes(classes(root))
      .filter(function(d) { return !d.children; }))
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.className + ": " + format(d.value); });

  node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.packageName); });

  node.append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".3em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.className.substring(0, d.r / 3); });
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In routes add entry:

```
match "flare" => "some_controller#index"
```

And in controller:

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => { 1 => "First", 2 => "Second"} }
  end
end
```